# Whether ArcGIS can use the IIS published image as the base image and not use ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I posted the tile base map on IIS. I wanted to load it through ArcGIS for JS, but I could not use ArcGIS Server.

Just like OpenLayers

```
var center = ol.proj.transform([112.233778,22.688963], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'); 
var map = new ol.Map({
    view: new ol.View({ 
        center: center,
        zoom: 1, 
    }),
    target: 'map'
}); 
var offlineMapLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        url: 'http://localhost:2674/roadmap/{z}/{x}/{y}.png' 
    })
}); 
map.addLayer(offlineMapLayer);
```

Or MapBox

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', // container id
    style: {
        'version': 8,
        'sources': {
            'raster-tiles': {
                'type': 'raster',
                'tiles': [
                    'http://localhost:2674/roadmap/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
                ],
                'tileSize': 256,
                'attribution':
                    'Map tiles by <a target="_top" rel="noopener" href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, under <a target="_top" rel="noopener" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a>. Data by <a target="_top" rel="noopener" href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>, under <a target="_top" rel="noopener" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0">CC BY SA</a>'
            }
        },
        'layers': [
            {
                'id': 'simple-tiles',
                'type': 'raster',
                'source': 'raster-tiles',
                'minzoom': 0,
                'maxzoom': 22
            }
        ]
    },
    center: [-74.5, 40], // starting position
    zoom: 2 // starting zoom
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is as much an ArcGIS JavaScript question, as it is "can IIS serve a tile basemap" question..... Which my initial take is no. But you don't provide much information about your tile basemap, so perhaps it's possible.

Comment: You can use Geoserver to do this http://geoserver.org/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you already have the tiles as pre-created images, then IIS can host them, and the ArcGIS API for JavaScript (like OpenLayers and MapBox) can access those images. The [WebTileLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-WebTileLayer.html) is the layer type you are looking for.

See e.g. https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-WebTileLayer.html#urlTemplate and a live sample at https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/layers-webtile-3d/index.html

You can specify the URL either as http://localhost:2674/roadmap/{level}/{col}/{row}.png or, starting with version 4.17 that was released a few weeks ago, http://localhost:2674/roadmap/{z}/{x}/{y}.png

```
new WebTileLayer({
    urlTemplate: "http://localhost:2674/roadmap/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
    copyright: 
        'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com/">Stamen Design</a>, ' +
        'under <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a>. ' +
        'Data by <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a>, ' +
        'under <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0">CC BY SA</a>.'
});
```